# Toggle Show And Hide Only Some Table Rows

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I am trying to show/hide (via a toggle mechanism) only certain rows in my table.   I have gotten somewhat close, code is below.  What I was reading about in other questions regarding this is the use of style id's and I have tried that but it fails for me.  So that is why I used 'hide=yes' and pass that into the toggle function.

This is going to be a table with a couple of hundred entries that when I click toggle can be reduce down to less than 30 on any given day.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
        function toggle(thisname) {

           tr=document.getElementsByTagName('tr')

           for (i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
              if (tr[i].getAttribute(thisname)){
                 if ( tr[i].style.display=='none' ){
                    tr[i].style.display = '';
                 }
              else {
                 tr[i].style.display = 'none';
                 }
              }
           }
        }
   </script>
   </head>

<body>

<span onClick="toggle('hide');">TOGGLE</span><br /><br />

<table>
   <tr ><td >display this row 1</td></tr>
   <tr hide=yes ><td>hide this row 1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>display this row 2</td></tr>
   <tr hide=yes ><td>hide this row 2</td></tr>
   <tr hide=yes ><td>hide this row 3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>display this row 3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>display this row 4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>display this row 5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>display this row 6</td></tr>
   <tr hide=yes ><td>hide this row 4</td></tr>
   <tr hide=yes ><td>hide this row 5</td></tr>
   <tr><td>display this row 7</td></tr>
   <tr hide=yes ><td>hide this row 6</td></tr>
   <tr hide=yes ><td>hide this row 7</td></tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems ok, i suggest you declare variables `tr` and `i`

alternately you could use `class` instead

```
 <span onclick="toggle('yes');">

 if (tr[i].className == thisname){

 <tr class=yes>
```

Comment: Yes, this works.  Thank you.  Is it better to use classname from a perspective of speed or readability, both?

Comment: Getting the className would be faster than finding the attributes value i think, you can do some tests to be sure for the speed